# Number of real values of x that satisfy this determinant?

Tags: matrices, determinant

How many real values of $x$ satisfy the following determinant?

$$
\begin{vmatrix}
x   & 3x+2 &  2x-1 \\
2x-1 & 4x  & 3x+1 \\
7x-2 & 17x+6 & 12x-1 \\
\end{vmatrix} = 0
$$

If we expand the determinant, it should give us an equation of the third degree. So, there should be either three or one real solutions for it, as imaginary solutions only exist in pairs. Is my reasoning correct? And how do I find the exact number of solutions?

Do there exist both objective amd subjective solutions for this question? I'd like to know both.

Thank you so much!

Comment: What's a subjective solution?

Comment: Like Alice says something, Bob says something else and Charlie decides who to give credit to based on who's got more *savoir faire*?

Comment: @SaucyO'Path Ah, no. What I meant by a subjective solution was one that uses properties and theorems to get to the answer, instead of solving by taking different values for the variable.

Comment: For problems like that in general, I think you just have to calculate the determinant in terms of x by some means, set it equal to 0, and solve for x (or analyze the resulting equation).

Comment: @LeonardBlackburn So basically, expand the determinant, and then solve for x? But that would take too long and end up being quite complicated. I was hoping there would be a shorter method.

Comment: @PlatinumTheHitgirl  Well, there are other ways to find the determinant than by cofactor expansion. You can use elementary row or column opertions, for instance. But, yes, you have to find the determinant to figure out the nature of the solutions. One answer below already pointed out that the third row is three times the first plus twice the second. So, elementary row opertions would quickly establish that the determinant is 0. So, there was a gap in your logic. The determinant might not be 3rd degree. The degree could be smaller (or the determinant could vanish).

Comment: @LeonardBlackburn I understand now. Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denoting by $L_i$ the $i-$th row, you have 
$$L_3 = 2L_2 + 3L_1$$

so the determinant is $0$ for all values of $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that determinant is $0$, for each real number $x$.